# Nested for loop complexity when number of elements differ

Tags: algorithm

Say I had a set containing n entries, and a set containing m entries, and the following nested for loop structure:

```
for 1 to n

  for 1 to n

    for 1 to m
```

What would the time complexity be? I want to say O(mn^2) but can this be simplified anymore so we just have a single variable?

Thanks.

Comment: If there is no relation between `n` and `m`, then this is the best you can do.  If `n` is a function of `m` (or vice versa), then simply make the substitution, and make any simplifications as necessary.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth in this case n represents vertices in a graph, and m represent edges in the corresponding edge set.

Comment: Wouldn't it be `O(n^2 * m)`?

Comment: In that case, it's very common to see both variables in the big-O expression (see [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your case,the answer seems obvious that the complexity would be O(mn^2)...

But,as you mentioned that n and m represent number of vertices and edges respectively,then also, there doesn't exist any direct relationship between `no. of edges` and `no. of vertices` for a general graph.

So,then also,the complexity would be O(mn^2)...

Comment: typo, was meant to say I wanted to answer (m * n^2) :)

Comment: See my explanation and try to grasp the thing as it is a good question!

Answer (score -2):

If `n` is the number of vertices in a graph, and `m` is the number of edges in that graph, then `m` is O(`n`^2), so that your algorithm would be O(`n`^4).

Comment: Why is `m` in `O(n^2)`?  I guess that's a loose upper-bound if parallel edges aren't allowed.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: If the graph were fully connected, there would be n(n-1) edges.  And the whole *point* of O() is to provide an upper bound.

Comment: Sure, but generally you want the tightest one possible.

Comment: @ScottHunter-Exactly I agree with Oliver sir. You should frame answer for general cases,not the special one!

Comment: OP asked for an expression involving just one variable, n.  And I explicitly *didn't* answer a special case; I used it to as an outlier to explain my answer.